# concatenating string with multiple array

Tags: awk

I'm trying to rearrange from a specific string into the respective column.
Here is the input

```
String 1:  47/13528 
String 2:  55(s) 
String 3:   
String 4:  114(n) 
String 5:  225(s), 26/10533-10541 
String 6:  103/13519 
String 7:  10(s), 162(n) 
String 8:  152/12345,12346
(d=dead, n=null, s=strike)
```

The alphabet in each value is the flag (d=dead, n=null, s=strike).
The String with value (digit) which is "String 1" will be the 47c**1**
etc:

```
String 1:  47/13528 
value without any flag will be sorted into the null column along with null tag (n)
String 1 (the integer will be concatenated with 47/13528)


Sorted : 
null
47c1@SP13528;114c4;103c6@SP13519;162c7


Str#2:  55(s)
flagged with (s) will be sorted into strike column

Sorted :
strike
55c2;225c5;26c5@SP10533-10541;162c7
```

I'm trying to parse it by modifying previous code, seems no luck

```
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        num  = $i+0
        abbr = $i
        gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/,"",abbr)
        list[abbr] = list[abbr] num " c " val ORS
    }
}
END {
    n = split("dead null strike",types)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        name = types[i]
        abbr = substr(name,1,1)
        printf "name,list[abbr]\n" 
    }
}
```

Expected Output (sorted into csv) :

```
dead,null,strike
,47c1@SP13528;114c4; 26c5@SP10533-10541;103c6@SP13519;162c7, 152c8@SP12345;152c8@SP12346,55c2;225c5;162c7;10c7
```

Breakdown for crosscheck purpose:

```
dead
none 

null
47c1@SP13528;114c4;103c6@SP13519;162c7;152c8@SP12345;152c8@SP12346;26c5@SP10533-10541;;162c7

strike
55c2;225c5;10c7
```

Comment: Could you please post your efforts too in form of code and let us know then. also your samples are not clear so please do add logic of how you are getting expected output too thank you.

Comment: let me know if you need any more info

Comment: It's not hard to debug your script. First you 'd see that it prints literally `name,list[abbr]` so you have to remove quotes in order to print the variables. Then you see what it prints, if it is not the desired output, you can add a few `print` statements inside your loop, to see what is being done for a line.

Comment: This row `String 7:  10(s), 162(n)` makes one item for `s` and one for `n`. This row `String 5:  225(s), 26/10533-10541` should make one item for `s` and one for `n` as you have said that `n` is default when no type exists. But in your example output, this row makes two items for `s` (based on the first `s`?) which makes your description **not determinative** for the output you really want.

Comment: sorry missed that one, the expected output has been edited

Comment: Still I see two values in the output sorted as `s` and not following your description: `26c5@SP10533-10541` and `162c7`.

Comment: good catch, it has been updated

Comment: `String 8:  152/12345,12346` What happens with the second `12346`?

Comment: Can you clarify the input format. Do all the strings appear in a single input line (as implied by the code), or over multiple lines (as implied by the sample input, with "String 1: ...", "String 2" structure) ?

Comment: Can you explicitly clarify the output separator: Semi colons between fields, and '@sp' between the dead/null/strike groups ?

Comment: `sorted into csc` what is the sorting order and what do you mean by "sorted"? I see `10` on the end `26c5@SP10533-10541;;` - is the double `;;` a typo?

Comment: @KamilCuk it’s going to be 152c8@SP12345;152c8@SP12346, It’s going to repeated , and with only single ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk script for parsing your file.

```
BEGIN {
    types["d"]; types["n"]; types["s"]
    deft = "n"; OFS = ","; sep = ";"
}

$1=="String" {
    gsub(/[)(]/,""); gsub(",", " ")    # general line subs
    for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {
        if (!gsub("/","c"$2+0"@SP", $i)) $i = $i"c"$2+0    # make all subs on items
        for (t in types) { if (gsub(t, "", $i)) { x=t; break }; x=deft } #find type
        items[x] = items[x]? items[x] sep $i: $i    # append for type found
    }
}

END {
    print "dead" OFS "null" OFS "strike"
    print items["d"] OFS items["n"] OFS items["s"]
}
```

Input:

```
String 1:  47/13528 
String 2:  55(s) 
String 3:   
String 4:  114(n) 
String 5:  225(s), 26/10533-10541 
String 6:  103/13519 
String 7:  10(s), 162(n) 
String 8:  152/12345,12346
(d=dead, n=null, s=strike)
```

Output:

```
> awk -f tst.awk file
dead,null,strike
,47c1@SP13528;114c4;26c5@SP10533-10541;103c6@SP13519;162c7;152c8@SP12345;12346c8,55c2;225c5;10c7
```

---

Your description was changing on important details, like how we decide the type of an item or how they are separated, and untill now your input and outputs are not consistent to it, but in general I think you can easily get what is done into this script. Have in mind that `gsub()` returns the number of the substitutions made, while doing them also, so many times it is convenient to use it as a condition.

Comment: Thank you so much, you’re so helpful.  What does “finalize section” do. Could you point me any handbook to refer

Comment: It is not a terminology (I will change that comment as you said that). I mean "finish them". After that line, the items are ready as strings with an additional `n` or `s`, if exists. The first `gsub()` replaces `/` with what you want. So `if !(gsub())` means if no replacement happened, means this item is not like `26/1234` but like `25n` so append the c-number part. By this line we do all replacements at once.

Comment: Also GNU awk string functions reference is useful https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Comment: Just realised that 152c8@SP12345;12346c8 should be, 152c8@SP12345;152c8@SP12346, but nwm it my bad again due to not consistent. anyway, Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

My usuall approuch is:

1. First preprocess the data to have one information on one line.
2. Then preprocess the data to have one information in one column row wise.
3. Then it's easy - just accumulate columns in some array in `awk` and print them.

The following code:

```
cat <<EOF |
String 1:  47/13528 
String 2:  55(s) 
String 3:   
String 4:  114(n) 
String 5:  225(s), 26/10533-10541 
String 6:  103/13519 
String 7:  10(s), 162(n) 
String 8:  152/12345,12346
(d=dead, n=null, s=strike) 
EOF
sed '
    # filter only lines with String
    /^String \([0-9]*\): */!d;
    # Remove the String
    # Remove the : and spaces
    s//\1 /
    # remove trailing spaces
    s/ *$//
    # Remove lines with nothing
    /^[0-9]* *$/d
    # remove the commas and split lines on comma
    # by moving them to separate lines
    # repeat that until a comma is found
    : a
    /\([0-9]*\) \(.*\), *\(.*\)/{
        s//\1 \2\n\1 \3/
        ba
    }
' | sed '
    # we should be having two fields here
    # separated by a single space
    /^[^ ]* [^ ]*$/!{
        s/.*/ERROR: "&"/
        q1
    }
    # Move the name in braces to separate column
    /(\(.\))$/{
        s// \1/
        b not
    } ; {
        # default is n
        s/$/ n/
    } ; : not
    # shuffle first and second field
    # to that <num>c<num>(@SP<something>)? format
    # if second field has a "/"
    \~^\([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\([^ ]*\)~{
        # then add a SP
        s//\2c\1@SP\3/
        b not2
    } ; {
        # otherwise just do a "c" between
        s/\([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\2c\1/
    } ; : not2
' |
sort -n -k1 |
# now it's trivial
awk '
{ 
    out[$2] = out[$2] (!length(out[$2])?"":";") $1
}

function outputit(name, idx) {
    print name
    if (length(out[idx]) == 0) {
        print "none"
    } else {
        print out[idx]
    }
    printf "\n"
}

END{
    outputit("dead", "d")
    outputit("null", "n")
    outputit("strike", "s")
}
'
```

[outputs on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DimpledAcademicBase#main.sh):

```
dead
none

null
26c5@SP10533-10541;47c1@SP13528;103c6@SP13519;114c4;152c8@SP12345;162c7;12346c8

strike
10c7;55c2;225c5
```

The output I believe matches yours up to the sorting order with the `;` separated list, which you seem to sort first column then second column, I just sorted with `sort`.